# PGPool not working with HikariCP in SpringBoot application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pgpool

I have enabled replication for Postgresql and I am using PGPool to make load balancing.

I am having issues to connect to Postgres using  HikariCP and even with Apache DBCP.

Is there a way to use PGPool in SpringBoot application?

Please find the configuration file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://192.168.177.148:9999/test
    username: myUser
    password: XXXXXXX
  jpa:
    properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: DEBUG
```

Please find the stack trace:

> 2018-08-10 10:20:19.124  INFO 37879 --- [           main]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
>   2018-08-10 10:20:20.617 ERROR 37879 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: unable to bind
>     Detail: cannot get parse message ""
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.SetupQueryRunner.run(SetupQueryRunner.java:53) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>
> 018-08-10 10:20:20.620  WARN 37879 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

More Trace

> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: unable to bind
>     Detail: cannot get parse message ""
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]

More Trace

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: unable to bind
>     Detail: cannot get parse message ""
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 61 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: unable to bind
>     Detail: cannot get parse message ""
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.SetupQueryRunner.run(SetupQueryRunner.java:53) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.runInitialQueries(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:674) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]

Comment: What error/stacktrace do you get? Also, share the configuration files/classes if possible

Comment: Hi @RajaAnbazhagan, Thanks for reply. I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Our Scenario**

We have also almost the same issue on the Kubernetes cluster. The database was closed and HikariCP not able to validate the connection properly. The exception is given by a spring boot application like below:

```
2020-01-06 09:38:13.013  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@490c2ee7 (This connection has been closed.)

2020-01-06 09:38:13.045  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection         : Validating connection.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:333) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]

    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]
... common frames omitted

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null

    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:295) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1947) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar!/:42.2.2]

    ... 111 common frames omitted
```

**Solution**

To fix this issue we supply the following properties for Hikari in spring boot application.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold=5000  
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=900000  
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
```

**References**

- https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1237
- [HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2a84e649 (This connection has been closed.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536053/hikaripool-1-failed-to-validate-connection-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgconnection2a)